# type command in bash

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash and while trying the "type" command with an argument like "cd" (`type cd`)which should return

```
cd is a shell builtin
```

but it throws `no such file or directory`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: what shell are you using? And you should post the exact command you ran.

Answer (score 3):

It depends in which shell you are. `type` itself is a shell buitin, hence if the shell has no builtin called `type` and there is no executable in `$PATH` it will throw the error `no such file or directory`.

For example in `csh`, there is no `type` command. Use the `which` command instead:

```
user@host:~$ csh
# which cd
cd: shell built-in command.
# exit
user@host:~$
```

Comment: :-)  Exactly what I was going to say, so an upvote!  ;-)